# Cannot find 'CombineLatest' in scope

Tags: swift, combine

I'm following along with the WWDC 2019 'Combine in Practice' video and I get the following error

```
Cannot find 'CombineLatest' in scope
```

I did it in a playground made in Xcode 12

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Stuff {
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var passwordAgain: String = ""

    var validatedPassword: AnyPublisher<String?, Never> {
        // wtf? "Cannot find 'CombineLatest' in scope"
        return CombineLatest($password, $passwordAgain) { password, passwordAgain in
            guard password == passwordAgain, password.count > 8 else { return nil }
            return password
        }
        .map { $0 == "password1" ? nil : $0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Has the API changed since 2019? Because it seems that

```
CombineLatest($password, $passwordAgain) -> $password.combineLatest($passwordAgain)
```

Is this true? Can anyone find any formal documentation on if it's true and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nested under [`enum Publishers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers), so you'd access it like this:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest($password, $passwordAgain)
```

Alternatively, you can use it as an operator, which is arguably a more common way:

```
$password.combineLatest($passwordAgain)
```